# Entry Points in setup.py

Tags: python, command-line-interface

I am making a CLI in python using Click. This is my entry point script:

```
entry_points='''
    [console_scripts]
    noo=noo.noodle:downloader
''',
```

I have made a Package, I have added `import noodle` in the `__init__.py` file so that it could import the file noodle which contains the function `downloader()` - which needs to be executed by the `entry_point` script. But when I install the `setup.py`, I get an Error: `ImportError: No module named noo.noodle` when I run `noodle --help` in terminal?

Comment: Do a test. After you install your program by `$ python setup.py`, try to open Pyhton console (or iPython) and do `import noo.noodle`. If this fails, your setup did not manage installing required package and module.

Answer (score 1):

Directly from the [documentation on click.pocoo.org](http://click.pocoo.org/5/setuptools/):

#### yourscript.py:

```
import click

@click.command()
def cli():
    """Example script."""
    click.echo('Hello World!')
```

#### setup.py:

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(
    name='yourscript',
    version='0.1',
    py_modules=['yourscript'],
    install_requires=[
        'Click',
    ],
    entry_points='''
        [console_scripts]
        yourscript=yourscript:cli
    ''',
)
```

While if you have multiple commands in your CLI application, I usually create a click group like this:

#### **init**.py:

```
import click

@click.group()
@click.option('--debug/--no-debug', default=False, help='My test option.')
def cli(debug):
    """Add some initialisation code to log accordingly for debugging purposes or no"""
    pass  

@cli.command()
def configure():
    """Configure the application"""
    pass
```

And the `setup.py` file looks exactly the same as the one in the click documentation.