# How to set entry point for console script with multiple command groups for Python Click?

Tags: python, command-line, console, setuptools, python-click

Given that my library with `foobar.py` is setup as such:

```
\foobar.py
\foobar
    \__init__.py
\setup.py
```

Hierarchy of CLI in the console script:

```
foobar.py
    \cli
         \foo
             \kungfu
             \kungpow
         \bar
             \blacksheep
             \haveyouanywool
```

#### [code]:

```
import click

CONTEXT_SETTINGS = dict(help_option_names=['-h', '--help'])


@click.group()
@click.version_option()
def cli():
    pass

@cli.group(context_settings=CONTEXT_SETTINGS)
def foo():
    pass

@cli.group(context_settings=CONTEXT_SETTINGS)
def bar():
    pass

@foo.command('kungfu')
def kungfu():
    print('bruise lee')

@foo.command('kungpow')
def kungpow():
    print('chosen one')

@bar.command('blacksheep')
def blacksheep():
    print('bah bah blacksheep')

@bar.command('haveyouanywool')
def haveyouanywool():
    print('have you any wool?')
```

**How should I set my entry in `setup.py`?**

There are many examples but they only show a single command for a single entry point, e.g. [Entry Points in setup.py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23949425/entry-points-in-setup-py)

But **is it even possible to setup the console script with how the my `foobar.py` click script is structured?**

If not, **how should I restructure the commands in `foobar.py`?**

---

For context, I have this script for the `sacremoses` library: https://github.com/alvations/sacremoses/blob/cli/sacremoses.py

But I couldn't figure how to configure the `setup.py` to install the sacremoses.py script properly: https://github.com/alvations/sacremoses/blob/cli/setup.py

Comment: I am not clear on why you need more than one entry point? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I'm trying to allow the user to do something like `$ ./foobar foo kungfu --help` and `$ ./foobar bar blacksheep --help`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To make the entry points work in your example you need:

```
entry_points='''
    [console_scripts]
    command_line_name=foobar:cli
''',
```

What you are missing is an understanding of the meaning of:

```
command_line_name=foobar:cli
```

#### [console_scripts]

There are three things in `command_line_name=foobar:cli`:

1. Name of the script from the command line (`command_line_name`)
2. Module where the click command handler is located (`foobar`)
3. Name of the click command/group in that module (`cli`)

#### setup.py

For your github example, I would suggest:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import setuptools

console_scripts = """
[console_scripts]
sacremoses=sacremoses.cli:cli
"""

setup(
    name='sacremoses',
    packages=['sacremoses'],
    version='0.0.7',
    description='SacreMoses',
    long_description='LGPL MosesTokenizer in Python',
    author='',
    license='',
    package_data={'sacremoses': [
        'data/perluniprops/*.txt', 
        'data/nonbreaking_prefixes/nonbreaking_prefix.*'
    ]},
    url='https://github.com/alvations/sacremoses',
    keywords=[],
    classifiers=[],
    install_requires=['six', 'click', 'joblib', 'tqdm'],
    entry_points=console_scripts,
)
```

#### Command Handler

In the referenced branch of your github repo, there is NO cli.py file.  The **[code]** from your question needs to be saved in `sacremoses/cli.py`, and then combined with the suggested changes to your setup.py, everything should work fine.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification in the answer!!